# Use constructor arguments to evaluate final values depending on each other. Flutter / Dart

Tags: constructor, dart, flutter, initialization, widget

I have a widget that takes a number representing pages allowed to be displayed on the screen. 
If the device is weak a `bool` can be passed that overrides the initial value.
However, since all values are final I must evaluate it in the constructor before the value is set.

```
class _A extends StatefullWidget{

  _A(this.limitPages, 
    this.pagesToDisplay: limitPages ? 10 : pagesToDisplay,
  )

  final int pagesToDisplay;
  final bool limitPages;
}
```

I could declare it in the initializer list, but then I can't pass an argument for `pagesToDisplay`.

```
class _A extends StatefullWidget{
  _A(this.limitPages)
    :this.pagesToDisplay: limitPages ? 10 : pagesToDisplay

  final int pagesToDisplay;
  final bool limitPages;
}
```

Is there any way to assert a statement in/before the constructor sets the final value?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want to use a parameter in the initializer list, the parameter can't be an initializing parameter, and you need to do the initializing in the initializer list instead:

```
class _A {
  _A(bool limitPages, int pagesToDisplay)
      : limitPages = limitPages,
        pagesToDisplay = limitPages ? 10 : pagesToDisplay;

  final int pagesToDisplay;
  final bool limitPages;
}
```

Comment: Yes, thanks. I was afraid changing the variable name would break the lib for existing users, but naming it the same should remove that obstacle.

Comment: Right, as long as you keep the same name it does not break users of this code.

Comment: Follow up question:
If I have a third property that depends on the result of pagesToDisplay, how do I chain it so that I can evaluate this value with the previous one?
For example `scrollDistanceToBottom = pagesToDisplay/screenWidth`
This will give the error `only static members can be accessed in initializers `.
Do i need to use the previous statement to re-evaluate the same value again? 
i.e. `scrollDistanceToBottom = (limitPages ? 10 : pagesToDisplay)/screenWidth`

Comment: This is not supported. There is no way to introduce variables in the initializer list that could hold values. You can either calculate the value twice or alternatively you can change your constructor to a private constructor and add a public factory constructor that calculates values and forwards pre-calculated values to the private constructor so that there no calculation (or not even an initializer list) is required..

Comment: That's a great Idea!
I guess it's out of reach for the open library in working on though.
Since it would break for all current users.
You don't happen to know about any literature discussing refactoring  public libraries with backwards compatibility?

Comment: I don't think it would break anything if the factory constructor gets the name from the previous regular constuctor and the previous regular constructor is renamed to a private name like `_A._(this.limitPage, this.pagesToDisplay);`. I don't think there is any literature. The Dart and Flutter team are often discussing such things in issues and how to make this easier, but I don't know any write-up that would summarize this topic.

Comment: You *can* refer to an initializing formal in the initializer list, so `_A(this.limitPages, int pagesToDisplay) : pagesToDisplay = limitPages ? 10 : pagesToDisplay;` is valid. Since the `pagesToDisplay` argument is ignored when `limitPages` is true, it seems wasteful to pass it, and it would probably be better to have two constructor:
`_A.limited() : limitPages = true, pagesToDisplay = 10;` and `_A.pages(this.pagesToDisplay) : limitPages = false;`.